# I am writing a code for my class and I have to figure out what number 1 through 9 occurs most in a list and return it and this is what I have so far

Tags: python

I am not getting the right numbers. Each time I try and upload it and change things I'm only getting a few of the answers correct and not all, and I'm not sure why.

This is my current code:

```
def most_common_element(lst):
    common = 0
    lst = (lst)
    one = lst.count(1)
    two = lst.count(2)
    three = lst.count(3)
    four = lst.count(4)
    five = lst.count(5)
    six = lst.count(6)
    seven = lst.count(7)
    eight = lst.count(8)
    nine = lst.count(9)
    if two > one:
        common = 2
    if three > two:
        common = 3
    if four > three:
        common = 4
    if five > four:
        common = 5
    if six > five:
        common = 6
    if seven > six:
        common = 7
    if eight > seven:
        common = 8
    if nine > eight:
        common = 9
    if one > nine:
        common = 1

return common
```

Comment: Learn to use loops to get rid of all the repetition.  Also think about what happens when counts are equal.

Comment: Think about what happens when `one` is 2, `two` is 3, and `nine` is 1.  learn to use a debugger to step through code and watch the logic.

Comment: Checking if `five > four` is not enough -- you **also** need to check if five is _bigger than any of the previous numbers_.  So you need to keep track of the biggest one as you step though all the comparisons.

Comment: What if you have to count one million numbers instead of nine? Would you make one million variables and conditionals? If something feels that there should be a better way it's probably because there's a better way. I'd recommend you first take a look at a python tutorial, so you get familiar with the basic features of the language

Comment: It's not like it's hard to find examples of how to count unique elements in a list in Python anyway. The take the `max`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask] in general.

Comment: What is your question? You forgot to ask it.

Comment: @Kelly They're new and haven't taken the tour so they probably don't realize this is a Q&A site. Go easy on them. I pointed them to some resources in my comment above. Personally, I can't think of a way to turn this into a good question since the entire approach is wrong, so that's why pointed them to "homework questions"; talking to their teacher (or peers or TA) would probably be more helpful.

Comment: @wjandrea I informed them about an important issue in nine words so they can easily fix it. You're trying to overwhelm them with three different long pages (and the last one contains numerous further links). I think I **am** the one going easy on them.

Answer (score 0):

That's way too much code and way too many steps.  You only need three steps.

First, make a new list that has all of the counts of the numbers 0-9 from the input list.

Then find the maximum value in that new list.

Then find that maximum value's position in the new list and return it.

```
def most_common_element(lst):
    # make a new list that has the counts for numbers 0-9
    counts = [lst.count(x) for x in range(10)]

    # find the largest count
    most = max(counts)

    # find its position and return it
    return counts.index(most)
```

Comment: That's way too much code and way too many steps. You only need one step: `from statistics import mode as most_common_element`

Comment: @KellyBundy To be fair, the exercise most likely wants the student to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Then `return max(range(10), key=lst.count)`?